# Issues with UI rendering (Weird border/title bar shadows)

Tags: user-interface

Recently the UI on my system started to render a bit weirdly. As can be seen in screenshots below, the title bar has a weird drop shadow on it (although subtle) and window border shadows became very extreme.

Furthermore, small transition animations such as when scrolling through the apps in the 'Applications' menu disappeared. The transition is now instant.

Any idea on how to fix this?

[image: Drop shadow and title bar]